# Passing an object into a Cypress cy.setcookie() Command

Tags: cookies, cypress

I have a cookie with several objects, namely path, secure status, and httponly status, that I need to set alongside the actual value of the cookie. While the Cypress guide does specifically state that such objects can be passed in, there is no example of a command with passed in objects for a novice like me to follow.

Can someone provide an example?

Already tried...

```
cy.setcookie('cookieName', 'value', 'path=/', 'Httponly=true', 'Secure=true')
cy.setcookie('cookieName', 'value', path='/', Httponly=true, Secure=true)
```

Answer (score 4):

The third parameter should be an `options` object, just a normal plain old Javascript object. That would look like this in your example:

```js
cy.setcookie('cookieName', 'value', {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
})
```